# php pages with htaccess redirect not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect non-www to www on my php site and keep urls clean without having to link to .php pages.

When I employ a suggested redirect for non-www to www below, the page links no longer go to proper pages. For example: I have a page1.php and when I link to domain.com/page1 (without .php) that page will no longer load. How can I fix this? Do I have to modify all links and add page extention (.php) for links to work?

htaccess I'm using:

RewriteEngine On

```
#This bit rewrites your host name to include www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#This bit does the codeigniter magic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: HAve you set up your routes for `/page1` or do the `page1.php` files not physically exist?

Comment: all of my pages are in page.php format. But links are /page /page1 /page2 etc...

Comment: so are you using CodeIgniter or not? Generally speaking its not jsut some magic you drop on a site and it makes the URLs work like you want. You need to convert those pages into Controllers and Views, and then set up your routes appropriately. IF you have done this, then give us some specifics about your routing so we can help cause the `.htaccess` directives arent enough to go on.

Comment: No, its a plain website with .php pages

Comment: Then you need to remove those last 3 directives. However you are going to have to use `thepage.php` to access the pages which means changing all the links. Im curious as to how you had this working before...

Comment: That only rewrites non-www to www.. the rest of my links get broken. Page Not Found (since links point to a page without .php extenstion)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Rewrite bare to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```